# Ошибка в запросе к SafeMySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Не могу понять, где ошибка? При выполнении запроса получаю 500 Internal Server Error

```
require('mysql.class.php');

$opts = array(
    'user'    => 'admin',
    'pass'    => 'PASSWORD',
    'db'      => 'admin_database'
);

$db = new SafeMySQL($opts);

$user_data = array();
$user_data['network'] = 'manual';
$user_data['name'] = $_GET['name'];
$user_data['email'] = $_GET['email'];
$user_data['sex'] = $_GET['sex'];
$user_data['ip'] = $_GET['ip'];
$user_data['clickID'] = $_GET['c'];
$user_data['city'] = $_GET['city'];
$user_data['country'] = $_GET['country'];
$user_data['user_lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
$user_data['age'] = $_GET['age'];
$user_data['token2'] = $_GET['t2'];
$user_data['token3'] = $_GET['t3'];

sendUserToDataBase($user_data, $db);

function sendUserToDataBase($data, $db) {

    $isExsist = $db->getOne('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?s',$data['email']);

    if($isExsist === false) {

        $sql  = "INSERT INTO users SET name=?s, network=?s, email=?s, city=?s, country=?s, user_lang=?s, sex=?s, age=?s, ip_adress=?s, token2=?s, token3=?s";
        $db->query($sql,$data['name'], $data['network'], $data['email'], $data['city'], $data['country'], $data['user_lang'], $data['sex'], $data['age'], $data['ip'], $data['token2'], $data['token3']);

        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Находи-читай логи, телепаты на карантине.

Comment: меня интересует, есть ли ошибка в самом коде? или код составлен верно?

Comment: Ошибка доступным языком описана в логе.

Comment: Код на первый взгляд нормальный. Ошибку надо смотреть в логах. Либо, если сервер не публичный, включить обображение ошибок на экран. display_errors = 1

Answer (score 3):

а не проще ли было сделать

```
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO users SET ?u";
    $db->query($sql,$data);
```

Comment: еще как вариант - сделать email уникальным полем, и использовать просто "insert ignore into ..." вместо предварительного запроса проверки